# Deserializing JSON object using JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I am trying to deserialize this JSON object, then insert it to the database:

```
{
    "PresiderEmailAddress": "kyitss@gmail.com",
    "MeetingNumber": "ME021616",
    "MeetingName": " Quotation Meeting",
    "MeetingDescription": "NULL",
    "MeetingDate": "2\/16\/2016",
    "MeetingVenue": "Consular Room",
    "TimeStarted": "12:00:00",
    "TimeEnded": "13:00:00",
    "CompletionRate": 0.0,
    "Remarks": "Actions still in progress"
}
```

But my WCF Service always gives me this error

> Invalid JavaScript property identifier character: }. Path '', line 1, position 19.

What am I doing wrong here? Here's my code, btw:

```
public Int32 InsertMeeting(string jsonMeetingDetails)
{
    MeetingDetailsForDeserializing obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MeetingDetailsForDeserializing>(jsonMeetingDetails);

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        Int32 insertResult;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into dbo.Meeting(MeetingNumber, PresiderEmailAddress, MeetingName, MeetingDescription, MeetingDate, MeetingVenue, TimeStarted, TimeEnded,CompletionRate, Remarks) values(@MeetingNumber, @PresiderEmailAddress,@MeetingName, @MeetingDescription, @MeetingDate, @MeetingVenue, @TimeStarted, @TimeEnded, @CompletionRate, @Remarks)");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MeetingNumber", obj.jMeetingNumber);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PresiderEmailAddress", obj.jPresiderEmailAddress);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MeetingName", obj.jMeetingName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MeetingDescription", obj.jMeetingDescription);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MeetingDate", obj.jMeetingDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MeetingVenue", obj.jMeetingVenue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeStarted", obj.jTimeStarted);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeEnded", obj.jTimeEnded);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompletionRate", obj.jCompletionRate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", obj.jRemarks);

        connection.Open();
        insertResult = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();

        if (insertResult == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I was looking for examples last night and it seems that the class I used to deserialized the objects didn't match the JSON. And also according to the post below, I changed it from this:

```
[DataContract]
public class MeetingDetailsForDeserializing
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string jPresiderEmailAddress { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string jMeetingNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string jMeetingName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string jMeetingDescription { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string jMeetingDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public string jMeetingVenue { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 6)]
    public string jTimeStarted { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 7)]
    public string jTimeEnded { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 8)]
    public decimal jCompletionRate { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 9)]
    public string jRemarks { get; set; }

}
```

to this:

```
[DataContract]
public class MeetingDetailsForDeserializing
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string PresiderEmailAddress { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string MeetingNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string MeetingName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string MeetingDescription { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string MeetingDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public string MeetingVenue { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 6)]
    public string TimeStarted { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 7)]
    public string TimeEnded { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 8)]
    public decimal CompletionRate { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 9)]
    public string Remarks { get; set; }

}
```

but I stil have to test it and see if it works. BTW, how can I test this using Fiddler?

**EDIT** Well, WCF gave me another error when I tested it on Fiddler:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: d. Path '', line 0, position 0.

I checked the JSON sample. There's no way there would be unknown characters.

Comment: when debugging, after deserialize is obj really contains the right data?

Comment: When debugging, does the jsonMeetingDetails string actually look like that? Is it possibly HTML encoded? Or contain escape characters? EDIT: Actually it looks like it could be caused by the escape characters in MeetingDate

Comment: @FelixAv I can't even see the data because it keeps giving me the Invalid Javascript error

Comment: @MaxJ I think so. I'll try and see if that is really the problem

Answer (score 0):

Quite hard to tell without seeing the contents whilst running, but as MaxJ mentioned it could be to do with the escape characters in MeetingDate so try popping an @ sign in front of "2/16/2016" to negate them.

Answer (score 0):

Why you prefixed j with your properties of MeetingDetailsForDeserializing? You json string should match with the properties. I tried to mimic the same json that you have and I am able to deserialize it successfully. Initially I was expecting the date error, but that didn't happen. Can you show the class MeetingDetailsForDeserializing ?

However, here are the snaps of the test I tried.

 **JS model**

```js
var data1 = {
            "PresiderEmailAddress": "kyitss@gmail.com",
            "MeetingNumber": "ME021616",
            "MeetingName": " Quotation Meeting",
            "MeetingDescription": "NULL",
            "MeetingDate": "2\/16\/2016",
            "MeetingVenue": "Consular Room",
            "TimeStarted": "12:00:00",
            "TimeEnded": "13:00:00",
            "CompletionRate": 0.0,
            "Remarks": "Actions still in progress"
        };
```

[image: After receiving the json data in string parameter "data", I am deserializing it. You can see the object expansion. All the properties are filled with the values.]

[This is the c# model class]

```
 [DataContract]
public class MeetingDetailsForDeserializing
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string MeetingNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string PresiderEmailAddress { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string MeetingName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string MeetingDescription { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public DateTime MeetingDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public string MeetingVenue { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 6)]
    public string TimeStarted { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 7)]
    public string TimeEnded { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 8)]
    public string CompletionRate { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 9)]
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
}
```

Let me know, if I am missing something.

Comment: Please instead of posting pics, edit your answer and post a formatted code.